# How to access a control in a third party software in C#?

Tags: c#, controls, autohotkey

I have an AHK script:

```
 SendMode, Input
;SetKeyDelay, 10, 10

f6::
   MouseGetPos,,, hwin
   clipboard := ""
   Loop
   {
      ControlFocus, Edit1, ahk_id %hwin%
      ControlSend, Edit1, {Ctrl down}{PgUp}{Ctrl up}, ahk_id %hwin%
      ControlSend, Edit1, {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}, ahk_id %hwin%
      if (clipboard != "")
         break
    }
return
```

This script copies the content of the "Edit1" control of a third party application to the clipboard. Is it possible to do something similar in C# ?
(The quoted AHK script do the copy if users hits F6, in the C# script I don't need that part, I only want to know how to reach and copy the content of a control of a third party application.)

Answer (score 0):

AHK is open source so simply look at how it translates those commands into win32 api